# if image is exist for xbmc

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, xbmc

I have the list of images that I wrote in xml and I can be able to run them on xbmc.

Here is the list of the images in the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<window type="dialog">
    <allowoverlay>no</allowoverlay>
    <coordinates>
        <system>1</system>
        <posx>0</posx>
        <posy>0</posy>
    </coordinates>

<controls>
    <control type="image" id="1">
       <description>Image1</description>
       <posx>307</posx>
       <posy>7</posy>
       <width>164</width>
       <height>102</height>
       <visible>true</visible>
       <texturefocus>image1_blue.jpg</texturefocus>
       <texturenofocus>image1_yellow.jpg</texturenofocus>
       <onup>2</onup>
       <ondown>3</ondown>
       <onleft>1</onleft>
       <onright>1</onright>
    </control>

    <control type="image" id="2">
       <description>Image2</description>
       <posx>471</posx>
       <posy>7</posy>
       <width>201</width>
       <height>102</height>
       <visible>true</visible>
       <texturefocus>image2_yellow.jpg</texturefocus>
       <texturenofocus>image2_blue.jpg</texturenofocus>
       <onup>2</onup>
       <ondown>3</ondown>
       <onleft>1</onleft>
       <onright>1</onright>
    </control>

    <control type="image" id="4">
       <description>Image3</description>
       <posx>671</posx>
       <posy>7</posy>
       <width>177</width>
       <height>102</height>
       <visible>true</visible>
       <texturefocus>image3_yellow.jpg</texturefocus>
       <texturenofocus>image3_blue.jpg</texturenofocus>
       <onup>2</onup>
       <ondown>3</ondown>
       <onleft>1</onleft>
       <onright>1</onright>
    </control>

    <control type="image" id="6">
       <description>image4</description>
       <posx>848</posx>
       <posy>7</posy>
       <width>176</width>
       <height>102</height>
       <visible>true</visible>
       <texturefocus>image4_yellow.jpg</texturefocus>
       <texturenofocus>image4_blue.jpg</texturenofocus>
       <onup>2</onup>
       <ondown>3</ondown>
       <onleft>1</onleft>
       <onright>1</onright>
    </control>
</controls>
</window>
```

I want to know how do you write on if statement in python for xbmc that if the image is exist and I want to know how I can change the image with id?